# Closing Browser and Opening in New Browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

Could I have JavaScript in a page where if a certain browser is detected (IE), it closes that browser and opens the same page in another browser (Chrome/Firefox)?

Comment: That is not possible.

Comment: Please have a look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . Having said that I feel what you're looking for may not be possible with javascript.